# Failed to instantiate after performing grunt serve:dist

Tags: angular, gruntjs

My angular app works okay when I run, `grunt serve`, but it gives

> `Failed to instantiate module toastr due to:`
>   `Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'toastr' is not available!`

error when running the same with `grunt serve:dist`.

Now I know many have asked this same question, but none of the answer solves my problem.

The thing is, I think that the problem is somehow involved with me running some different versions of some plugin. I say this because a colleague of mine had the same code successfully compiled in his PC.

So getting the correct versions might help me. This are the following external tools and my package.json and bower.json file.

**bower.json**

```json
{
  "name": "********",
  "Author": "*********",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "angular-block-ui": "^0.2.2",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.2.18",
    "ngstorage": "^0.3.10",
    "angular-toastr": "^2.1.1",
    "highcharts": "^6.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.19.3",
    "bootstrap-timepicker": "^0.5.2",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.7.1",
    "daterangepicker": "^1.6.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "angular-daterangepicker": "^0.2.2",
    "infinite-scroll": "^3.0.2",
    "angularjs-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.11.8",
    "alasql": "^0.4.4",
    "angular-datatables": "0.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "infin8",
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    }
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": ">=1.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.19.3",
    "jquery": ">=1.7.1 <4.0.0"
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "infin8",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-core": "^5.2.1",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-angular-templates": "^0.5.7",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.12.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-filerev": "^2.1.2",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "^0.4.3",
    "grunt-jscs": "^1.8.0",
    "grunt-karma": "*",
    "grunt-newer": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-postcss": "^0.5.5",
    "grunt-svgmin": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "^3.0.0",
    "grunt-wiredep": "^2.0.0",
    "jit-grunt": "^0.9.1",
    "jshint-stylish": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "*",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "*",
    "time-grunt": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-material-time-picker": "^1.0.7",
    "autoprefixer-core": "^5.2.1",
    "bower": "~1.8.0",
    "compass": "^0.1.1",
    "datatables.net-responsive": "^2.2.0",
    "datatables.net-responsive-dt": "^2.2.0",
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-angular-templates": "^0.5.9",
    "grunt-cli": "~1.2.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "^1.1.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.12.3",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^1.0.1",
    "jit-grunt": "^0.9.1",
    "jshint-stylish": "^1.0.2",
    "time-grunt": "^1.4.0",
    "wiredep": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

and these are my tools version.

- grunt-cli v1.2.0
- grunt 0.4.5
- bower 1.8.2
- npm 5.6.0
- node 9.4.0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it right. For some reason I was using angular version 1.5.11, (***go figure***).

I always had the doubt that changing my angular version would set the build right, but *ya know* business rules and the "use of" old and tested frameworks, ummm... so yeah.

It is such a relief now.

Anyway, changed my version to 1.6.8, ran **grunt serve:dist**, got the login page alongwith some errors but *atleast* I got something, that is more than enough for me now.

*P.S.* the .json files were from my colleague.

**Edit:**
    Still error. I will keep on posting if i make any breakthroughs.

Comment: If you're minifying your code, remove that step from the process and see if the error still occurs.